# select with trim trailing blanks of char in db2

Tags: db2, db2-luw

how do I remove trailing blanks in a select on a char(32)?

```
db2 "create table test (col1 char(32))"
db2 "insert into test values ('one')"
```

I tried

```
db2 "select cast(trim(t ' ' from col1 ) as varchar(32)) from test"
db2 "select trim(t ' ' from cast(col1  as varchar(32)) from test"
db2 "select cast(trim(t ' ' from cast(col1  as varchar(32))) as varchar(32)) from test"
```

... but I always have trailing blanks

Comment: How do you determine that you have trailing spaces?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try

```
select trim(cast(col1 as varchar(32))) from test
```

proof it with

```
select length(trim(cast(col1 as varchar(32))) ) from test
```